# How multiple locators for element are working?

Tags: ruby, watir

I have following HTML:

```
<a class="js-open-modal suspend" data-track-event="interacted_with_account_manage_settings_web" 
 data-track-properties="{&quot;location&quot;:&quot;clients&quot;,&quot;button_clicked&quot;:&quot;Suspend&quot;}" data-track="always"
href="/client_suspension/new?client_id=86">Suspend</a>
```

and I've declared element (button) with these two locators:

```
link(:suspend_button, :class => ["js-open-modal", "suspend"])
link(:suspend_button, :visible_text => 'Suspend')
```

I've tried to "broke" first locator : `link(:suspend_button, :class => ["blah-blah-blah-blah", "suspend"])` and test works with second locator: `link(:suspend_button, :visible_text => 'Suspend')`.

This provides resilient tests.

But if I "broke" second locator `link(:suspend_button, :visible_text => 'Ssssssuspend')`, than the test does not work with first locator: `link(:suspend_button, :class => ["js-open-modal", "suspend"])`.

Page is:

```rb
class MyClientsPage < Base
  include PageObject


  link(:suspend_button, :class => ["js-open-modal", "suspend"])
  link(:suspend_button, :visible_text => 'Suspend')

end
```

and the test is:

```rb
require 'spec_helper'
require "rspec/expectations"

describe 'Partner/client switch' do

  it 'Client account is suspended' do
    on(MyClientsPage).suspend_button
  end
end
```

What is the magic behind the scenes when combining multiple locators using Watir?
Could you please share more examples.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using page object model?

Comment: Are you saying you included both of those `link` declarations in the same page-object at the same time?

Comment: @JustinKo, yes I left both link declarations and ran tests.
I've edit the question -> example code is added.

Answer (score 0):

When a page-object defines multiple accessors with the same name, there is no magic for combining the locators. Instead, the last definition wins.

The accessors methods, eg `link`, dynamically define methods for the page-object. Effectively the page-object:

```
    class MyClientsPage < Base
      include PageObject

      link(:suspend_button, :class => ["js-open-modal", "suspend"])
      link(:suspend_button, :visible_text => 'Suspend')
    end
```

Is converted to something like:

```
    class MyClientsPage < Base
      include PageObject

      def suspend_button
        browser.link(:class => ["js-open-modal", "suspend"]).click
      end

      def suspend_button
        browser.link(:visible_text => 'Suspend').click
      end
    end
```

As with all of Ruby (not specific to Watir or Page-Object), if you define the same method twice, the last definition basically overwrites the previous one. This is why you could modify the first accessor without any impact - ie you are modifying a definition that gets thrown away.

If you want to locate a link that has the specific class *and* the visible text, you need a single accessor:

```
    class MyClientsPage < Base
      include PageObject

      link(:suspend_button, :class => ["js-open-modal", "suspend"], :visible_text => 'Suspend')
    end
```